# If I store users username and password in cookies, for next time users logged in if they were clicked the remember me, is that a good idea?

Tags: authentication, web-application, cookies, account-security

I built new web application. 
In my login system I make remember me check box, 
If user clicks on that then his/her username and password will stored in cookies so for next time they will logged in without any asking those credentials. Is that a secure way? or what else a good way for better security issue?

Comment: if the cookie is stolen, then the account is lost

Comment: There is a LOT already written on this. This was my first google hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website

Comment: No this is not secure. Do not implement this.
It is best to use either existing frameworks which offer this functionality (e.g Django or Laravel). Also have al ook here: https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build/